# Exercise for exam about comparing string on file

Tags: c, string, file, compare

I'm trying to do this exercise for my exam tomorrow.

I need to compare a string of my own input and see if that string is appearing on the file. This needs to be done directly on the file, so I cannot extract the string to my program and compare them "indirectly".

I found this way but I'm not getting it right, and I don't know why. The algorithm sounds good to me.

Any help, please? I really need to focus on this one.

Thanks in advance, guys.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void comp();

int main(void)
{
    comp();

    return 0;
}

void comp()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("e1.txt", "r+");

    if(!file)
    {
        printf("Not possible to open the file");
        return;
    }

    char src[50], ch;
    short i, len;

    fprintf(stdout, "What are you looking for? \nwrite: ");
    fgets(src, 200, stdin);

    len = strlen(src);


    while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        i = 0;

        while(ch == src[i])
        {
            if(i <= len)
            {
                printf("%c - %c", ch, src[i]);
                fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR + 1);
                i++;

            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "This needs to be done directly on the file, so I cannot extract the string to my program and compare them "indirectly"."  That's exactly what you're doing though.  What do you think fgetc does?  It loads the character into your program...

Comment: I meant I cannot bring the file into a string on my program. Sorry I didn't explain explain myself

Comment: You can read the data from the file into a buffer without NUL terminating it, thus it would not be a string. Then use `memcmp()`.

Comment: The given answers fix your main problem, but they still will fail to find, for example, the string "aab" in the string "aaab". Because after the third 'a' is encountered, they will reset i to 0, "forgetting" that 2 'a's were already encountered. Bottom line is, you need a stack of some sort.

Comment: I've edited simonc's answer by an fseek() considering Taylor's comment (not the most elegant solution, but a simple one). I hope it will be visible soon after the peer review

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt It looks like your edit was rejected.  I can't see what change you proposed now.  Why don't you post a comment to the answer instead?  Or post a new answer if your change offers a substantial improvement over my suggestion.

Comment: `ch` should be declared an int, not a char.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic after matching the first character looks suspect.  There's no need to seek in the file, you need to read more content to try to match the later bytes from `src` and resetting `i` on each iteration prevents you from checking later characters from `src`.

The following (untested) code should be closer to the mark

```
i = 0;
while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if (ch != src[i]) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else if (++i >= len) {
        printf("found %s in file\n", src);
        break;
    }
}
```

It relies on repeated calls to `fgetc` rather than `fseek` and only resets the index into `src` when a character doesn't match.

Note also that

```
char src[50];
fgets(src, 200, stdin);
```

is slightly wrong.  It tells `fgets` that it can write up to 200 `char`s to `src`.  Writing any more than 50 will write beyond the memory allocated for `src`, with undefined consequences.  You should change this to

```
char src[50];
fgets(src, sizeof(src), stdin);
```

Comment: you're perfecty right: this has been my suggested edit directly before resetting `i = 0`:  `if( i > 0 ) { fseek(file,i*-1,SEEK_CUR); }`. So if you search for "ab" and you have "aab", you will examine the second "a" twice and you will have a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
    if(ch != compare[i]){
       i = 0;
     }
    else{
    i++;
     }

    if(i >= strlen(compare){
    printf("we have a match");
    break;
     }


}
```

Comment: Minor point but you should initialise `i=0` outside the loop now.  If the OP pastes your updated loop into his code, the first test for `ch!=compare[i]` will use an uninitialised value for `i` and may crash.